# What is the convention for Racket filename extensions?

Tags: racket

`.rkt` is the conventional file extension for 'regular' Racket source code. In the documentation, I also see [`.rktl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl)))) and [`.rkts`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/load.html) being used. What are `.rktl` and `.rkts` used for, and are there any more Racket filename extensions I am not aware of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.rkt` file extension is generally used for files that represent *modules*. These normally have a [`#lang ....`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._hash-lang%29) line at the top, or sometimes [`(module ....)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._module-syntax%29). They can be imported as modules with [`require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-require.html).

The `.rktl` and `.rkts` file extensions are used for files meant to be loaded at the top-level that aren't modules. They don't necessarily have a [`#lang ....`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._hash-lang%29) line at the top, and must be *loaded* in some external environment with [`load`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html#(def._((quote._%7E23%7E25kernel)._load))) instead of imported with require. These usually have a more "dynamic" feel to them, and they're used more often with scripts that use mutation of variables across multiple files. This is not the "encouraged" style in Racket.

The `.rktd` file extension is used for files that just have *data* encoded as s-expressions, not code. These files should not be required or loaded (they should not be *executed* as code). However, other programs use them to store data on the file system using `write`, and to read the data later using `read`. Its purpose is the same as a `.sexp` file or a `.json` file, just pure data.

Comment: So `.rktl` and `.rkts` are interchangeable?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've seen `.rktl` used for load-scripts, but I've actually never seen `.rkts` used in actual code before.

Comment: I don't see any `.rkts` files in the racket source directory. So it wouldn't surprise me if its an old extension, or if someone else uses it to generate Racket code, or if you are thinking of something like `rktc`, which is racket pre-processed c code.

Comment: @LeifAndersen `.rkts` is used in the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/load.html).