# What are .rkt~ files and what purpose do they serve?

Tags: racket

This question is about the `.rkt~` files that are generated when working with `.rkt` files using [DrRacket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/). Actually I am not sure if this is specific to DrRacket, but that is the IDE I am using at the moment.

They seem to store the same information as the program with the same name with the `.rkt` extension, except they are not updated as frequently. I am wondering what purpose they serve, as this would inform how I handle them in version control and whether/when I delete them.

What I have found so far:

- This seems related to the question, [What is the convention for Racket filename extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52929243/21891079), but no where is the `.rkt~` extension discussed in the question or in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.rkt~` files are what as known as "First Change Files", and `.rkt~` is the Unix/MacOS extension for these files. On Windows, the extension is changed to `.bak`, not `.rkt~`. They store the state of an existing file before changes were made with DrRacket.

See the following from the documentation, [DrRacket Files](https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/drracket-files.html#(part._drracket-autosave-files))

> Separately [from backup files], DrRacket creates “first change” files. When you modify an existing file in DrRacket and save it, DrRacket copies the old version of the file to a special first-change file if no such file exists. The first-change file is saved in the same directory as the original file, and the first-change file’s name is generated from the original file’s name...